# Equations of motion for $\mathcal{L}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}F_{ab}F^{ab} }$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, variational-calculus

How do I find the equations of motions of a Lagrangian of this type:

$$
\mathcal{L}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}F_{ab}F^{ab} }
$$

And are they equivalent to $\mathcal{L}_{EM}=-\frac{1}{4}F_{ab}F^{ab}$?

---

$$
\begin{align}
0&=\partial_\mu \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu A_\mu)}\\
&=\partial_\mu \frac{\partial }{\partial (\partial_\mu A_\mu)} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}F_{ab}F^{ab} }\\
&=\partial_\mu \frac{\partial }{\partial (\partial_\mu A_\mu)} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} (\partial_a A_b-\partial_bA_a)(\partial^aA^b-\partial^bA^a) }\\
&=\partial_\mu \frac{\partial }{\partial (\partial_\mu A_\mu)} \sqrt{(\partial_a A_b\partial^aA^b-\partial_bA_a \partial^aA^b) }\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \frac{1}{\sqrt{(\partial_a A_b\partial^aA^b-\partial_bA_a \partial^aA^b) }} \frac{\partial }{\partial (\partial_\mu A_\mu)} (\partial_a A_b\partial^aA^b-\partial_bA_a \partial^aA^b) \\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \frac{1}{\sqrt{(\partial_a A_b\partial^aA^b-\partial_bA_a \partial^aA^b) }} F^{\mu\nu}
\end{align}
$$

Can the term under the square root be eliminated?

Comment: Note that your derivative should be $\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)}$ - you've used the index $\mu$ too many times.

Comment: $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\alpha A_\beta-\partial_\beta A_\alpha)(\partial^\alpha A^\beta-\partial^\beta A^\alpha)}\neq \sqrt{\partial_\alpha A_\beta \partial^\alpha A^\beta-\partial_\beta A_\alpha \partial^\alpha A^\beta}$

Answer (score 2):

Take the derivative $\partial_{\mu}$ carefully, then identify the common denominator and note that for a fraction to vanish you need its numerator to vanish.

Answer (score 1):

There are various issues with taking the square root of the Maxwell Lagrangian  ${\cal L}_{EM}=-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$:

1. The argument of the square root should be non-negative.
2. The square root Lagrangian ${\cal L}=\sqrt{{\cal L}_{EM}}$ does *not* reproduce Maxwell's equations, essentially because $\frac{d{\cal L}_{EM}}{dx^{\mu}}$ does not vanish on-shell. See also e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2506272/11127) related Math.SE post.

Speaking of the square root, it seems natural to mention the [Born-Infeld Lagrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93Infeld_model).